# MySQL - getting from random column but specifying amounts

Tags: sql, mysql, random, mysql-error-1064

I would like to do this

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Thoughts 
ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 1 WHERE ups > 5
```

...but it is returning an error. Do you know an alternative around that? I'm a bit new to MySQL, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the clauses is important.  Do

`SELECT * FROM Thoughts WHERE ups > 5 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Also, in the future, post the error you that you're getting.  "An error" is amazingly unspecific.

Comment: Thank you, and I didn't title it "An error", not sure what you're talking about?

Comment: @someWalri - "..but it is returning an error." ... This should have been the exact error message being returned.  "an error" gives no useful information.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Guess I was in a hurry! But thank you, it works now.

Comment: @someWalri - Yup, no worries.  Just trying to help your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

order by rand() may cause performance issue, instead try to do in following way:

```
 // what NOT to do:  
 $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Thoughts WHERE ups > 5 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");  

 // much better:  

 $r = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM Thoughts WHERE ups > 5 ");  
 $d = mysql_fetch_row($r);  
 $rand = mt_rand(0,$d[0] - 1);  

  $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Thoughts WHERE ups > 5  LIMIT $rand, 1");
```